# C# AOP Transaction Aspect

Tags: c#, .net, aop, transactionscope

My problem is related to the undoing of the actions I have done when the error is received.

In the project that I am developing on .Net core 5, I can undo these transactions with Transection scope aspect using AOP. But I need a new solution. Let's assume that 5 crud transactions are sent to the db in the transaction.
If one of these 5 crud operations fails. I want the 3 transactions I sent to be reversed and 2 of them not to be reversed.
how do i do this.

thank you for your help.

```
 public class TransactionScopeAspect : MethodInterception
    {
        public override void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                try
                {
                    invocation.Proceed();
                    transactionScope.Complete();
                }
                catch (System.Exception e)
                {
                    transactionScope.Dispose();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm waiting generic TransactionScopeAspect

Comment: I came across such a question in a job interview and I gave the same answer as you. But the company I talked to was a company that wrote bank software. He said that in some cases there are such transactions. I've been wondering how I can do it and I've been researching and couldn't find many examples.

Answer (score 0):

If the 5 crud operations belong to the same transaction there is no way you can have 3 completed and 2 reversed operations. A transaction by default is either completed as a whole or rejected as a whole. If you need more granularity you will need a different strategy like the [saga pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/saga/saga) but that might be overkill. From the linked doc:

> Use the Saga pattern when you need to:
>
> - Roll back or compensate if one of the operations in the sequence fails.

In short: perform the crud operations in sequence. If one fails that you will need to compensate/reverse the previous executed operations. If it is the first one that is simple, obviously. The more operations / failure point the more complex it will become.